# Unable to configure NDK android studio and get errors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-ndk

I am new to android development.i am trying to integrate / configure NDK
but i am getting problems.

i have tried every solution available on web. like removing white paces for android SDK and NDK paths. which i did not get any white space.
i have updated my gradle version.also tried to reinstall the ndk.
tried to change project directory and rfresh the prject again and again.
i will appreciate if some one help me to sort out this issue. i am putting screenshots.
and i will provide more information to explain if required. thankx[image][image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside Android.mk file

For Mac:

Remove

```
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/$(ARCH_PATH)/lib.so
```

And Add

```
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./lib/$(ARCH_PATH)/lib.so
```

Comment: should i add both lines in android.mk ?

Comment: @Logic "Inside Android.mk file"

Comment: i have added screen shots of android mk files. where i should edit?

Comment: can you share the application.mk file?

Comment: navigate to `libs/armeabi-7a` and check if `libx264.a` exists

Comment: can i get your skype ? even i can pay for this task. or can you start chat.because much commenting is not allowed here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179689/discussion-between-logic-and-anubhav-gupta).